# Simple.... Pass perl variable to ajax success ?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

Can anyone please let me know how can i pass a variable from perl subroutine back to ajax's success part for further manipulation ?

Here is the code for understanding more in detail

```
sub File_Check {
    print header('application/json');
    if (-e $filename) {
        my @file_check=();

        if (open(TXT,">>$filename")){
            close TXT;
            $file_check[0] = TRUE;} 
        else {
            $file_check[0] = FALSE;
        } 

        my $json->{"entries"} =\@file_check;
        my $json_text= to_json($json);
        prin $json_text;
    }
}
```

The perl subroutine is File_Check. It will check if the file is open or not. If open, $file_check[0] variable would have TRUE as result. I want to pass this result in the below ajax success method.

```
$.ajax({
        url: perlURL,
        data: { action: "File_Check"},
        type: 'get',
        datatype: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            // data should be returned here for manipulation. 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error');
        }                                                                       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the [`success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is the data received from the server:

> **success**
>
> Type: `Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

You can specify the `dataType` as JSON, and send the appropriate content type and response from the Perl side.

Comment: Unur- I edited my code after your inputs. can u please suggest me what i am doing wrong here. Any inputs are appreciated. I am still getting alert as "Error" from the ajax function's error.

Answer (score 0):

i got an answer for this. if it helps anyone, i wld be glad.

```
sub File_Check {
    print $cgi->header('text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
    if (-e $filename) {
        my $file_check="";
        if (open(TXT,">>$filename")){
            close TXT;
            $file_check="TRUE";
        } 
        else {
            $file_check="FALSE";
        } 
    print $file_check;
    }
}
```

The above one is a perl subroutine. heres the ajax call i made to get the data from perl subroutine.

```
var perlURL= "$thiscode";
\$.ajax({
        url: perlURL,
        type: 'post
        data: form_data,
        datatype: "script",
        success: function (result) {
        console.log(result); // gives true or false depending on value from perl subroutine.
        },
        error: function(result) {

        }
});
```